# Qt or GTK+, on which is better to spend time on?

Tags: user-interface

I'm at a crossroad. I have to choose to invest my time on learning an UI library. I googled so much about this topic, but the great part of the information are dated or not complete enough. I also read a number of questions on this site, but I'd be glad to have updated information.
The main question is: which UI library deserve to be studied and learned? And in the perspective of job, which kind of knowledge about this topic the companies request (GTK+, Qt, or other UI lib/toolkit)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to what your doing with them.

QT supports androind and windows CE. While GTK doesnt. 
However GTK is the default for GNOME.

Also GTK seems to have a much worse startup time if your looking at performace of the two.

[This is a great link comparing the two](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/GTK_vs_Qt)

If your goal is just learning the more popular one for jobs I would suggest QT based on indeeds trends [QT](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=QT&l=) Vs [GTK](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=GTK&l=)

I honestly think you should do a spike with each one for a day or two see which one you like more and go with that one. If you learn one you can easily learn the other down the road. However you will put forth more effort for one that you like out of your own will.